# I want to serve different private files to multiple users using MERN

Tags: javascript, database, ejs, mern

First, I am a newbie with bad English. So, I will create users(my clients) with username and password, I will give username and its password to them, when they open my site, they will login and will be served with their order(photos and videos) in folders, it should be private of course. I have no idea how to do this, I know basics of MERN, I am willing to learn more if I have to, I have time.

Please Help me just with the idea, how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a "username" and "password" property per user in each of your documents in your collection. If the username matches the password for the selected document, then you can fetch the other properties or data you have stored. This is the simplest answer I know.

```
username: "john",
password: "qwerty123",
photos:[],
videos:[]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).